# Redirect to specific page(Deeplink) after installing angular cordova app

Tags: android, angular, cordova

I have a requirement to connect specifc page in android/ios app from outside application after login(bypassing Home page).
If app is already installed in mobile ,I can do it.The difficulty I am facing when app is not installed,redirect to play /app store and install. After installation of app the page need to redirect specific page after successful login.
Is there any option to store any unique value in play store and app store for redirecting to specific page after successful login?
Kindly provide any other solution If you have.This is angular cordova project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase Deep links are the official way to solve this problem. If the app is not installed, the deep link will survive the installation process. Later you can use that deep link to navigate to any portion of your app.

Branch.io does the same job.

Comment: Thanks for you're response . But my requirement is redirect dynamic link after successful login. In Firebase dynamic I couldn't see that option.

Comment: You can do that. you simply create the dynamic link in firebase. even through the download the app phase, it will still hold the link for you to use when app is launched.